# Is it possible to find the vertices of an equilateral triangle given its center point?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I was wondering how to find the vertices of an equilateral triangle given its center point?

Such as:

```
        A
        /\
       /  \
      /    \
     /   M  \
  B /________\ C
```

Provided that `AB, AC, BC = x` and `M = (50,50)` and `M` is the middle of the triangle, I want to find `A`, `B` and `C`.

Thanks.

Comment: This is unsolvable since any rotation of a possible solution gives another. Are you enforcing that one of the points lies directly above the center? Then it's solvable

Comment: Is $x$ a known value? And do you want line segment $BC$ horizontal, as in the diagram? Without further restrictions such as these, there are infinitely many answers.

Comment: Not without further information regarding the orientation of the triangle.  Without that information, imagine rotating the triangle arbitrarily.

Comment: @AlexR. Yeah, I actually want that point A will be above the center (same Y value).

@RoryDaulton Yeah `x` will be a known positive number, and `BC` should be horizontal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume that $x$, the side of the equilateral triangle, is a known positive quantity and that side $BC$ is horizontal (or that point $A$ is directly above point $M$). Let's also assume you are using Cartesian coordinates (where increasing the first coordinate means moving right and increasing the second coordinate means moving up) and that $M$ is the point $(50,50)$.

Then $x$ is the side of the equilateral triangle $ABC$. By simple geometry we know that the altitude is $\frac{\sqrt 3}2x$. Point $M$ is the centroid of the triangle and is on the altitude which is also the median. This means the distance $AM$ is two-thirds the altitude, namely $\frac{\sqrt 3}3x$.

Therefore point $A$ is $\left( 50,50+\frac{\sqrt 3}3x  \right)$.

Point $B$ is $\frac{\sqrt 3}2x$ down from $A$ and $\frac x2$ to the left, so point $B$ is $\left( 50-\frac x2,50-\frac{\sqrt 3}6x \right)$, and point $C$ is $\left( 50+\frac x2,50-\frac{\sqrt 3}6x \right)$.

I tested this answer with Geogebra, and it checks.

Comment: Indeed works.. Thanks! I accepted this answer because it was the easiest to implement programmatically.

Comment: Yoou should probably define point $M$ as $(50, 50)$ somewhere.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot: Yes, you are right. I have added that to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Draw the circle of radius $\frac {\sqrt 3}3x$ around $M$. Pick an arbitrary point $A$ on this circle. Then intersect the circle of radius $X$ around $A$ with the first circle to determine $B,C$ as intersection points.

Note that $A$ could be picked anywhere on the circle, hence the result is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we are assuming that $BC$ is parallel to the coordinate axis. Now, we can get all the horizontal and vertical distances we need to solve this problem.

Let $P$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Note that we have $PC = BP = x/2$ and $MP = (x/2)/\sqrt{3}$. Finally, $MA = x/\sqrt{3}$. This should be enough to get all the coordinates.

EDIT: A better method, especially if the triangle can be in any orientation, is to first shift everything so that the center is at $(0,0)$. Now, we have that the distance from the center to any point is $R = x/\sqrt{3}$. Now, in complex numbers, we can express the three points as $R \cdot e^{i\theta}, R\cdot e^{i\theta + 2\pi/3}, R\cdot e^{i(\theta - 2\pi/3)}$. This is because each point is $120^\circ$ apart.

Now simplify shift everything back so that the center is $(50,50)$.